# MySQL foreign key cascade delete not working, completely stumped

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, cascade

I have read a bunch of other threads on this but I am still stumped.  I have created a two very simple tables as a sanity check and unable to get them to preform a cascade delete so need some help at this point.

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `test1_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test1_name` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test1_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test1_ID_UNIQUE` (`test1_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `test2_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test2_FK_test1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test2_name` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test2_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test2_ID_UNIQUE` (`test2_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_test2_FK_test1` (`test2_FK_test1`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_test2__test1` FOREIGN KEY (`test2_FK_test1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`test1_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table data used for testing

```
Test 1 Table Data:
+----------+------------+
| test1_ID | test1_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | test1 r1   |
|        2 | test1 r2   |
+----------+------------+

Test 2 Table Data:
+----------+----------------+----------------+
| test2_ID | test2_FK_test1 | test2_name     |
+----------+----------------+----------------+
|        1 |              1 | Test2 R1 - FK1 |
|        2 |              1 | Test2 R2 - FK1 |
|        3 |              1 | Test2 R3 - FK1 |
+----------+----------------+----------------+

Insert statements:
INSERT INTO `test1` VALUES (1,'test1 r2'),(2,'test1 r2');
INSERT INTO `test2` VALUES (1,1,'Test2 R1 - FK1'),(2,1,'Test2 R2 - FK1'),(3,1,'Test2 R3 - FK1');
```

If I delete the first row from the test1 table nothing happens to the test2 table data

```
DELETE FROM test1 WHERE test1_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Weird. [This is supposed to work...](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dffd4a/1) (off-topic: your `UNIQUE` constraints are redundant, a PRIMARY KEY is already a unique constraint)

Comment: I have just tested your SQL exactly as above and it worked fine. On deleting the row from test1 the three rows were deleted from test2.

Comment: It may be a bug with my version of MySQL I am running 5.5.28, I will update it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the version of MySQL I was using, 5.5.28.  I just upgraded to 5.6.13 and everything works now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a little disturbing that the process that prepares MySQL for release failed to identify this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure mysql "foreign key checks" is enabled:

```
select @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;

set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that calling `PDO::exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1')` is necessary for PDO to respect `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` actions. For some reason, foreign key constraints are disabled by default on my system.